# How to encrypt and write RSA private key to file with PEM_Write_RSA_PrivateKey

Tags: c++, c, openssl

The function：

```
int PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(FILE *fp, RSA *x, const EVP_CIPHER *enc,
                                        unsigned char *kstr, int klen,
                                        pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
```

The way I call the function :

```
PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(pFile, pRSA,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,(void*)passphrase);
```

In openssl's documents,it says the last parameter is passphrase，but I find the context in the output file is not encrypted。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, because you set the cipher to NULL you won't get any encryption.

Go with something like:

```
PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(pFile,pRSA,EVP_des_ede3_cbc(),passphrase, passphraseLength,NULL,NULL);
```

And of course change the cipher as you please, better option would be to use AES-128-CBC, but it's up to your specific goal and performance requirements.

Don't forget to initialize the OpenSSL library with something like
`OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()`

Comment: The parameters(enc,kstr,klen) are not exsited in PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey.How to decrypt it?

Comment: You won't need the cipher in your code, it will be included in the PEM file. As for the password, pass it as the last argument (casting to void*).

Comment: PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(pfile, &pRSA, NULL, (void*)passphrase);

Comment: PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(pfile, &pRSA, NULL, (void*)passphrase);   I called the read function with the same passphrasa ,but it failed to read the privatekey.Is thera any way to find why it fails?

Comment: I call the write function like this 。PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(pFile, pRSA, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), (unsigned char*)passphrase, strlen(passphrase), NULL, NULL);

Comment: Well, "it fails" is not too much to go with, but you can certainly try initializing OpenSSL if you haven't done it earlier. `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();`

Comment: Before calling the write function,I called OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms().It works.Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, I've edited the answer, you can mark the topic as answered and closed.